# SwiftyStoreKit. Как отключить ввод пароля от AppleID при проверке подписки?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchases

Использую [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit).

Есть покупка: автообновляемая подписка.

Покупка проходит нормально.

Проблема:

Когда подписка уже оформлена, при запуске приложения на девайсе происходит проверка подписки через verifyReceipt.

Почти каждый раз появляется Эппловский Алерт, который просит вести пароль от AppleID.

Причем именно пароль, а не TouchID или FaceID.
Это очень раздражает.

Если пользователь нажимает Cancel или неправильно вводит пароль, то выскакивает ошибка проверки: Cannot connect to iTunes Store.

И пользователь не может попасть в приложение.

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы пароль от AppleID не запрашивался постоянно при проверке подписки (verifyReceipt)?

Comment: Это происходит в sandbox или в production AppStore?

Comment: И в sandbox, и в production.